# Filter a PivotTable for multiple values based upon cell values using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I have the following code in order to filter my PivotTable and it works well

```
Sub Macro1()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year")
        .PivotItems("2003").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2004").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2002").Visible = False
     End With
  
End Sub
```

However, I would now like to do the filtering dynamic so instead of the code showing the year in absolute values ("2003","2004","2005") I would like it to take a specific cell value

For example instead of "2003" it should be Year1 = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value
'In the example above cell F1 in the ActiveSheet is equal to 2003

However if I change the code to below I get an error message saying

"Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class"

```
Sub Macro1()

Year1 = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year")
        .PivotItems(Year1).Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2004").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2002").Visible = False
     End With
  
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me so that the PivotItems are based upon the cell values? Please note that the solution can't involve a "ClearAllFilters" on "Year" as that will then result in the PivotTable overlapping another PivotTable

I have tried renaming the cell F1 value instead of 2003 to "2003" to see if that would help but it didn't

I also tried to write the code as below if that would make any difference

```
Sub Macro1()

Year1 = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year")
        .PivotItems("""&Year1""").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2004").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2002").Visible = False
     End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see `Year1 = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value` in your Macro1 sub ?

Comment: @karma, I updated that in the code now so it is clear

Comment: In my side, when I dim the Year1 as string, `.pivotitems(Year1).visible=true` work. But if I don't declare Year1 with dim as string, you are right, it also throw me an error. So, maybe try : (1) have your cell F1 value in general format (just type 2003, not "2003"), and (2) put `dim Year1 as string` right after `Sub Macro1()`

Comment: @karma. Thank you so much for your assistance and your solution seems to have worked :)